# How to create a function "ExecuteSql" without consume too much memory

Tags: .net, vb.net

i wrote a .NET function :

```
Public Function ExecuteSql(strSql As String, connectionString As String) As SqlDataReader

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSql, conn)
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader

    Try
        conn.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)

    End Try

    Return dr

End Function
```

As you can see, this function return a datareader, so i can manipulate data as i like. 
The problem is: the connection remain open.

How to solve this problem ? Is there a command to 'close globally connection' ? 
Thanks

Comment: The title talks about memory consumption, you don't mention it in the question at all? What kind of memory are you worried about? Or is it just the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call

```
dr.close()
```

after you are done working with the data reader.  Alternatively, you can create a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx), and then use [Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx) to fill a DataTable. When using a datatable, you can close the connection right away, as soon as you call fill, and you don't have to wait until the code on the other side of your "ExecuteSQL" function is done as you do with the DataReader.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise that you not return a DataReader, unless you are using this in a very isolated spot in your code - @Kibbee answers correctly in stating that you need to explicitly close the reader when you are done, and if you expose this method throughout your app, you are adding a risk that you may forget to close a connection.

The DataReader is a one-way, once-only collection.  In my opinion, it was really designed for tasks like filling up a drop-down list.  Based on what you need the data for, there are lots of other approaches.

If you need to allow users to modify the data before saving changes back to the database, a DataSet/DataTable would probably be a better solution, it doesn't hold an open connection, and it lets you iterate forward/backward and search within the data.

Another common pattern is to create "Business Entities" or "Data Transfer Objects", which are disconnected from the database and which are used explicitly to hold data for binding and manipulation.  These can be generated or written to have similar structure to the underlying database data When it's time to save the changes, you will call in to ADO.Net or some other database technology to persist the changes.  There's a lot you can learn about Business Entities and Data Transfer Objects, but one of the problems these approaches solve is to help decouple your data access code and connections from other layers of your application.